# Transferred site doesn't show content with PMWiki

Tags: pmwiki

A relatively simple pmwiki site has been copied to a new server. All of the formatting (non-wiki) code works however the wiki content comes up as blank.
If I add a new page, that page shows up just fine.

I have checked the permissions and ownership of the files in wiki.d folder.  All files (new and old) look identical.

I have eliminated the search optimization file in hopes that the old would be treated like the new.

Is there another file that references older files that might be keeping them from being seen? Any ideas would be welcome.

I've never had this problem before in copying a pmwiki site.

Here is the site http://pecarru.mobilify.pw/

Here is the new page http://pecarru.mobilify.pw/index.php?n=Main.NewPage

All pages should have text in the white box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page-source](http://pecarru.mobilify.pw/index.php?n=Main.Testimonials&action=source) is available by appending `&action=source`, so that tells us there is no problem accessing the content.

Additionally, the content looks normal -- no weird characters that I can see (which sometime cause trouble on a new server).

However, I do see "smart quotes" in several pages; try changing changing them to dumb-quotes and see if the page will now render.

I see that the [WikiSandbox](http://pecarru.mobilify.pw/index.php?n=Main.WikiSandbox) page and content in the [PmWiki group](http://pecarru.mobilify.pw/index.php?n=PmWiki.PmWiki) renders, so it's not every page that has a problem.

If editing doesn't resolve the issue, try disabling recipes in `\local\config.php` until the content appears.
Something is choking on render.

Comment: It was the smart quotes and dashes and ampersands, although where they came from or why they have come into play I don't know. I LOVE the action=source flag. I've used pmwiki for years and never used that.  You're a life saver.